# Add a maximum length property on an XML attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="row">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="TestField" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How do I add a maximum length property on the TestField attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can restrict `TestField` to be a string of `xs:maxLength` of, say, 100 like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="row">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="TestField" use="required">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Do you know whats the limit of maxLength for xs:string?

Comment: I checked and it seems that there is no max? but I use this in SSIS where strings are limited to 4000.

Comment: Well, there're two related questions: (1) Is there a maximum length of an unrestricted xs:string?  and  (2) What is the maximum value one can specify for `maxLength` for a `xs:string`?  Both would be better asked as questions than comments.